# Perform a batch validation in Kafka and sent to corresponding topic

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have the following batch format stored in a Kafka topic:

```
Data generated -->  B2E, T3, T2, T1, B2S | B1E, T3, T2, T1, B1S  --> Data Consumed
```

Here `BS` indicate a batch start, `BE` indicates batch end and `t1,t2,t3` is three different data.

Here is the scanerio:

1. Before pushing batch end record `B1E` to the topic, we got to know that the `B1` batch is invalid after doing some validation.
2. In that case all data of `B1` batch ranging `BS` to `BE` should go to a particular topic.

So in above example `b1` batch should go to topic T1 and `b2` batch should go to T2.

How can I do that using Kafka.?

Comment: Use some windowing mechanism to store batch data until batch end record `BE ` is processed. After all the batch has been validated, publish the records to the relevant topic.

Comment: Can you share some example

Answer (score 2):

[image: simple flow digram]

According to the above picture, Read and validate each message by message and update some in the memory window (memory map with batch data) until the relevant batch end `BE` is received. After batch end `BE` received read relevant batch data from the window and publish all the batch records to the topic selected from processed (validated) results.

To windowing, you can use a memory map like <Key = BatchID> <Values = Array of Batch Data Object> or Kafka streaming [state store](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/architecture.html#state).

If you need something like a KStream solution, It will be a stream flow like below

[image: Kstream solution]

Comment: Here memory window is simple Map??

Comment: Yes. you can use a simple memory map data structure or some store implementation.

Comment: I am looking for a Kafka based solution

Comment: Data consumed -> processed -> publish according to processed results. So if you need to wait for batch end records, you need to window them in some state store. It is the Kafka Streaming possible solution. You can use something like Stream State Store or KTable.

Comment: Can you please suggest Kafka solution?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by Kafka solution

Comment: I meant using Kafka ecosystem only e.g using KSTream, state store, ktable etc

Comment: If you need to do this with Kstream, Start the stream from the topic where data available, and then add a `Process` to validate and write to the state store. Put a `Filter` to filter last batch event `BE`. After the filter add another `Process` to read all the batch messages from state store and publish to the sink topic.